# DbGeometry.IsEmpty fires NotImplementedException after upgrade EF 5->6

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am using EF spatial data types DbGeometry and DbGeography in my application. Now I tried to upgrade from EF5 to EF6. The project compiles (after I swapped all System.Data.Entity referencies to new ones of EF6), but at runtime when I try to access DbGeometry.IsEmpty I get NotImplemetedException. From refactored assemblies I found out, IsEmpty calls private field spatialProvider, which has two implementations - DefaultProvider and SqlServerProvider. Default one throws the exception. So how can I instruct EF to use the SqlServer one?

Couple of words for my architecture: Server communicates with DB via EF. On server it seems to work fine also, it's where I have EDMX and create all EF stuff. Than it sends a DTO to client via WCF, this DTO has a DbGeometry property. Than on client (WPF) I call IsEmpty on this DTO property and... exception. Is there some config or sth, coz on the client I don't have any EF schemas etc, just a reference to EntityFaramework 6 spatial types DLL.

PS: I do load unmanaged SQLTypes assemblies on the client also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, once you describe it, you eventually get to the answer. In case smb will ever run into the same problem: for methods like IsEmpty to work propertly (i.e. to use SqlServer implementation, not default one), one should add EntityFramefork NuGet package to the project. It adds reference not only to EntityFramework.dll, but also EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.

When I was changing my namespaces during upgrade, I just clicked add reference in ReSharper, and it automatically added reference to EntityFramework.dll only.